# Error while Installing AWS Toolkit on Visual studio 2017

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017

For installing AWS Toolkit on Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (15.7.4), I find Extensions and Update menu from Tools main menu , click Online menu (left side) and then type AWS Toolkit and press download. 
Then I close VS and VSIX installer start for installing AWS Toolkit. After while, it shows me a message like this

[image: The error box]

**I read all of the last questions about this subject and read all of them, but it seems it is different.** 
Also I attached the log file here.  [the error log file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/files/2170520/VSIXInstaller_033ee914-fcc9-4cc0-9184-95f13590e069.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete `oprpfoeu.n32` folder then download and run the installer again.

Comment: thanks for the reply. is it in system32 ? i read this solution in github before, i searched it but i could not find this folder.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\oprpfoeu.n32\

Comment: There is't this folder in extensions folder. I checked it. it is my problem ?

Comment: can you tell me what should be in this folder?

Comment: The same. But that folder doesn't exist. I tried to delete the folder with the AWS and try to reinstall, but the problem was not solved

Answer (score 0):

1. delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio\201X\YYY\MSBuild\Amazon Web Services LLC`
2. delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio\201X\YYY\Common7\IDE\Extensions\xxxxx.xxx` (where
   xxxxxx.xxx was the folder that contain AWS related dll's)
3. Re-installed AWS Toolkit

X= Year number
YYY= version: Professional,Community,...

Answer (score 0):

Deleting this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Amazon Web Services LLC
```

and installing the AWSToolkitPackage worked for me.