# AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017 : Install Failed

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017, aws-sdk

Similar with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211281/error-while-installing-aws-toolkit-on-visual-studio-2017) but I cannot find the folder which need to delete, but it seems it is different.

Please somebody help me as I am not able to install AWS Toolkit on my Laptop.
I am trying to install AWS Toolkit on Visual Studio Professional 2017 (15.9.9) from [MarKetPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.AWSToolkitforVisualStudio2017),  After double-click and install, it shows an error message as below

[image]

After I click Close button 
I got another error message as below:

[image]

```
Logfile indicated as
15/03/2019 4:23:06 PM - Found 'C:\USERS\PLH.TASDC\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_99AE3896\EXTENSIONS\o0tbv1ll.vvf\extension.vsixmanifest'
15/03/2019 4:23:06 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Desktop SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
15/03/2019 4:23:06 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\SDK ARM Additions\extension.vsixmanifest'
15/03/2019 4:23:06 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Windows Store SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
**15/03/2019 4:23:06 PM - Skipping 'C:\Users\plh.TASDC\AppData\Local\Microsoft SDKs' as it doesn't exist
15/03/2019 4:23:06 PM - Beginning to install extension to Visual Studio Professional 2017...
15/03/2019 4:23:07 PM - VSIX TaskScheduler: VSIX Auto Updatetask already exists.
15/03/2019 4:23:07 PM - Install Error : System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find setup engine instance.**
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineUtility.GetCurrentSetupInstance(IEngineHost engineHost)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.CreateEngine(IEngineHost engineHost, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, InstallFlags installFlags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can see it from the picture.

You need to install this plugin on your computer from the panel.